# Anyone have any luck fixing/attenuating wireless hits?

Tags: wireless, interference, noise-reduction, post-production

Hey Guys,

A buddy of mine recently came to me with a seminar vid that contains some pretty nasty RF hits. Unfortunately the only sources are the lav on the speaker and the onboard camera audio (which is, needless to say, extremely distant/buried in background noise). I've been messing around with Izotope to try and and alleviate the issue, but I'm having very little luck...

Thanks in advanced for any advice!

Comment: got any samples you can post for a listen online somewhere?

Comment: What issues are you hearing? Thumps, crackle, drop outs, static pops, clothing rustle?